# How to negate inverse a regex expression

Tags: java, regex, replace, inverse

I am using Java regex.
I have a String as follow

```
String s = "the location is at {emp.address.street} with the name {emp.name},{emp.surname}";
```

For above string, `s.replaceAll( "\\{(.*?)\\}", "" )` returns the following string:

`the location is at with the name ,`

Now I want to inverse this to get following result:

`{emp.address.street}{emp.name}{emp.surname}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tested script works for me:

```java
public class TEST
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String s = "the location is at {emp.address.street} with the name {emp.name},{emp.surname}";
        String result = s.replaceAll( "[^{}]+|(\\{(.*?)\\})", "$1" );
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great...Could you please explain how it works? what is the role of $1?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Pattern` and use `Matcher.find()` and `Matcher.group()` to get parts of that pattern.
Here's the Javadocs for the classes: [Matcher javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) [Pattern javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)